Best quantitative version of open mapping theorem in complex analysis
There is a "quantitative" version of the Open Mapping Theorem in complex analysis, saying:

Let $f$ be holomorphic on the closure of a disc $V$ around $c$, and assume $m := \min_{z\in \delta V} |f(z)-f(c)|$ is not $0$. Then $f(V)$ contains the open disc $B_{m/2}(f(c))$.

This is e.g. proved in section 8.5 of Remmert's textbook, and the proof is essentially reproduced in the accepted answer to this question, where, possibly for pedagogical reasons, the weaker $m/3$ instead of $m/2$ is used. Remmert says (p. 258) this proof goes back to Carathéodory's Theory of Functions of a Complex Variable, pp. 139/140.
I see that in this proof, the radius of the disc around $f(c)$ cannot be made bigger than $m/2$. However, if I draw (quite possibly too simple) sketches of the geometric situation, it looks as if the image should actually always contain $B_m(f(c))$.
Question: Is there an example of a function $f$, analytic on the closure of some disc $V$ around $c$, with $m := \min_{z\in \delta V} |f(z)-f(c)| > 0$ but $f(V)$ does not contain $B_m(f(c))$? If so, is $m/2$ indeed the best upper bound for the radius of an open disc around $f(c)$ guaranteed to be in $f(V)$?

Yes, you are right: If $m = \min_{z\in \delta V} |f(z)-f(c)|$ is positive then $f(V)$ contains the open disk $B_m(f(c))$.
For a bounded domain $V$ is $\partial f(V) \subset f(\partial V)$, see for example here or here. Then
$$
  \partial f(V)  \cap B_m(f(c)) = \emptyset \, ,
$$
so that $B_m(f(c))$ can not contain points of $f(V)$ and its complement. But $f(c) \in B_m(f(c))$, and therefore $B_m(f(c)) \subset f(V)$.
But note that the proofs of $\partial f(V) \subset f(\partial V)$ already use the open mapping theorem, so the above argument is not a new proof of that theorem.
